# How to highlight the row in Pandas Dataframe by condition on some cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I get Dataframe by pivot_table:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['labor_costs'],
                         index=['Division', 'Perfomer'],
                         columns=['completed on time'], aggfunc=[np.sum, len], fill_value=0)
```

[image]

How can I highlight the row by condition: on schedule == 0 and overdue == 0 like table above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Pandas stylers for coloring an entire row based on a given column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-column)

Comment: does this answer your question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102093/highlight-row-in-pandas-when-condition-match

Comment: I use function 'pivot_table' and I can't apply df['overdue'] or df['on shedule'] in my condition

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below highlights rows based on the condition you described.

[image]

You can customise the text and background colours, font weight and size, etc.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'schedule': np.random.choice([0, 12, 23], 11),
                   'overdue': np.random.choice([0, 132, 323], 11)})

def style_overdue(x):
    highlight = ['color:black;background-color:lawngreen;font-weight:bold']
    no_highlight = [''] #['color:white;background-color:black'] #can be customised
    condition = (x.schedule == 0) & (x.overdue == 0)
    return (highlight if condition else no_highlight) * len(x)
(
    df
    .style
    .apply(style_overdue, axis=1)
)
```